# How do I use tidyr to fill in completed rows within each value of a grouping variable?

Tags: r, tidyr

Say I have data on people who choose between several options.  I have one row per person, and I want to have one row per person and choice option.  So, if I have 10 people who have 3 choices, right now I have 10 rows, and I want to have 30.

All of the other variables should be copied to each of the new rows.  So, for example, if I have a variable for gender, that should be constant within ID.  (I am setting my data up this way to analyze with `mnlogit`.)

This seems like the situation that two `tidyr` functions, `complete` and `fill`, were designed for.  To use a simple example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
dat <- data.frame(
    id = 1:3,
    choice = 5:7,
    c = c(9, NA, 11),
    d = ymd(NA, "2015-09-30", "2015-09-29")
    )

dat %>% 
  complete(id, choice) %>%
  fill(everything())

# Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
# 
#      id choice     c          d
#   (int)  (int) (dbl)     (time)
# 1     1      5     9       <NA>
# 2     1      6     9       <NA>
# 3     1      7     9       <NA>
# 4     2      5     9       <NA>
# 5     2      6     9 2015-09-30
# 6     2      7     9 2015-09-30
# 7     3      5     9 2015-09-30
# 8     3      6     9 2015-09-30
# 9     3      7    11 2015-09-29
```

But this has some problems -- the values of d were carried forward correctly, but the values of c from ID 1 replaced the (correct) NA values for ID 2.

I could try a workaround, like replacing all of the missing values with 999, running `complete` and `fill`, and then replacing 999 with NA.  (I think I would have to convert the date variables to character variables and then convert them back again if I go this route.)  But maybe someone on here knows of a tidy way to do this with `tidyr`?

Edit: the desired output here is:

```
# Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
# 
#     id     c          d choice
#  (int) (dbl)     (time)  (int)
# 1     1     9       <NA>      5
# 2     1     9       <NA>      6
# 3     1     9       <NA>      7
# 4     2    NA 2015-09-30      5
# 5     2    NA 2015-09-30      6
# 6     2    NA 2015-09-30      7
# 7     3    11 2015-09-29      5
# 8     3    11 2015-09-29      6
# 9     3    11 2015-09-29      7
```

Comment: Sorry, `time` is supposed to be `choice`.  I'll fix that.

Comment: As an update, `mlogit` contains a function, `mlogit.data` that solves this problem.  `mlogit.data(dat, choice = "choice", shape = "wide")` also produces the desired results.  I know I asked for a `tidyr` solution, but, for future readers, I thought it might be helpful to include this solution as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the trick of "grouping" things to complete within complete using `c()`. This makes it so that it is only completed using preexisting combinations of the grouped variables.

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>% complete(c(id, c, d), choice) 
     id     c          d choice
  (int) (dbl)     (time)  (int)
1     1     9       <NA>      5
2     1     9       <NA>      6
3     1     9       <NA>      7
4     2    NA 2015-09-30      5
5     2    NA 2015-09-30      6
6     2    NA 2015-09-30      7
7     3    11 2015-09-29      5
8     3    11 2015-09-29      6
9     3    11 2015-09-29      7
```

Comment: Hm, okay.  So it seems like the solution here is `complete(c(id, c, d, [all other variables that don't change]), choice)`, and just leave off `fill` entirely.  Right?

Comment: I'll add it, but the desired output is produced by `complete(dat, c(id, c, d), choice)`.

Comment: Using `tidyr` version `0.5.1` this doesnt work anymore. See my answer below.

Answer (score 21):

As an update to @jeremycg answer. From `tidyr 0.5.1` (or maybe even version `0.4.0`) onwards `c()` does not work anymore. Use `nesting()` instead:

```
dat %>% 
 complete(nesting(id, c, d), choice)
```

**Note** I was trying to edit @jeremycg answer, since the answer was correct at the time it was written (and hence a new answer is not really necessary) but unfortunately the edit got rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're better off keeping the data separate while you prepare it, and then merging before you need to do the regression.

```
subjectdata <- dat[,c("id", "c", "d")]
questiondata <- dat[,c("id", "choice")] %>% complete(id, choice)
```

And then

```
> merge(questiondata, subjectdata)
  id choice  c          d
1  1      5  9       <NA>
2  1      6  9       <NA>
3  1      7  9       <NA>
4  2      5 NA 2015-09-30
5  2      6 NA 2015-09-30
6  2      7 NA 2015-09-30
7  3      5 11 2015-09-29
8  3      6 11 2015-09-29
9  3      7 11 2015-09-29
```

as necessary.  That way you also get a valid `d` column for user 2, without relying on the order of questions in the data frame.

Comment: You're probably right, this probably will be the cleanest way to do this, in the end.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like another approach is to use `spread` and `gather`.  `spread` creates one column per possible answer, and `gather` takes the separate columns and reshapes them into rows.  With these data:

```
dat %>%
  spread(choice, choice) %>%
  gather(choice, drop_me, `5`:`7`) %>%  # Drop me is a redundant column
  select(-drop_me) %>%
  arrange(id, choice)  # reorders so that the answer matches

#   id  c          d choice
# 1  1  9       <NA>      5
# 2  1  9       <NA>      6
# 3  1  9       <NA>      7
# 4  2 NA 2015-09-30      5
# 5  2 NA 2015-09-30      6
# 6  2 NA 2015-09-30      7
# 7  3 11 2015-09-29      5
# 8  3 11 2015-09-29      6
# 9  3 11 2015-09-29      7
```

I haven't done any testing to see how these compare in efficiency.